# Firebase Analytics - Web only activate after user consent

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

can anybody provide me some information how to disable / enable Firebase Analytics data collection depending on user consent? The official Firebase Documentation only mentiones iOS and Android - not Web. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection)

cheers